# Check if string has letter in uppercase or lowercase

Tags: c++, string, lowercase

i would like to know if it's possible check if one letter of a string is capitalized. Other way to see it, if all letters in the string are uppercase or lowercase.  Example:

```
string a = "aaaaAaa"; 
string b = "AAAAAa"; 

if(??){ //Cheking if all the string is lowercase
   cout << "The string a contain a uppercase letter" << endl;
}
if(??){ //Checking if all the string is uppercase
       cout << "The string b contain a lowercase letter" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Check out `isupper` and `islower`.  They will help you a lot.

Comment: From your example input, both `a` and `b` contain an uppercase and both contain a lowercase. What should distinguish them? My question is  when will uppercase check apply and when will lowercase check apply?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use standard algorithm [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
if( std::all_of( str.begin(), str.end(), islower ) ) { // all lowercase
}
```

Comment: `std::islower` hmm?

Comment: If you invert the condition: `!std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isupper)`, you would have early return.

Comment: @GillBates std::islower is ambiguous with the version from `<locale>`, requiring the user to static cast to the simple version.

Comment: @Mikhail but it is not equal, different result if for example the string has not letters

Comment: @krzaq If locale is included, that is

Comment: @GillBates Afaik all standard headers are free to include other standard headers...

Comment: if string contains numbers in any position of the string, will affect it to the condition result?

Comment: @jean yes, condition I wrote means `true if all symbols are lowercase letters`, what @Mikhail wrote `false if any of symbols is a uppercase letter`. Obviously result would be different for non letters. What is viable result is up to you.

Comment: @Slava I can't compile this algorithm, i'm using a little program to test, but it give  error: ‘all_of’ was not declared in this scope
   if ( !all_of(aux.begin(), aux.end(), &::isupper) ). I'm ussing c++ -g main.cpp and i have #include <algorithm>

Comment: @jean as stated in documentation it is available for c++11 or later, so add flag `-std=c++11` if you compile with gcc

Comment: I hope this comment isn't too pedantic, but the example is missing a closing parenthesis:   ` if (std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), islower)) { // all lowercase
 
 }`

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done with lambda expressions:

```
if (std::count_if(a.begin(), b.end(), [](unsigned char ch) { return std::islower(ch); }) == 1) {
    // The string has exactly one lowercase character
    ...
}
```

This assumes that you want to detect exactly one uppercase/lowercase letter, as per your examples.

Comment: 1. `count_if` is redundant, `any_of` fits better. 2. Lambda itself is redundant, just `std::islower` would be ok.

Comment: @Mikhail This [compiles and runs with lambda](http://ideone.com/qU2sLB) and [fails to compile without it](http://ideone.com/SmtZGG).

Comment: Yeah, I see, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496334/check-if-string-has-letter-in-uppercase-or-lowercase#comment68237169_40496404

Comment: @Mikhail As far as `any_of` goes, both OP's examples show exactly one upper/lower case letter, suggesting to me that he wants to see if there's exactly one such character. I added a note to that effect. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: @Mikhail, we need the lambda to convert to `unsigned char` (not doing so is Undefined Behaviour - see your usual reference for `std::islower`).

Answer (score 4):

Use `all_of` in concert with `isupper` and `islower`:

```
if(all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), &::isupper)){ //Cheking if all the string is lowercase
    cout << "The string a contain a uppercase letter" << endl;
}
if(all_of(a.begin(), a.end(), &::islower)){ //Checking if all the string is uppercase
    cout << "The string b contain a lowercase letter" << endl;
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e4gBaIyND40gCv64)

Alternatively, use `count_if`, if you want to check the number of letters matching your predicate.

Comment: The `&::isupper` trick is nice! [I tried compiling without it](http://ideone.com/SmtZGG) and got a rather cryptic error back. Now I understand it's because of an overload.

Comment: You should be using `<cctype>` and thus `std::islower` in C++ code.  More importantly, it's dangerous to pass plain char to `std::islower()` - always convert to unsigned before promoting to `int`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Why is it dangerous to pass plain char to `std::islower`? I can't think of a scenario where it could cause problems. [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/cctype.syn) defines `<cctype>` to be identical to `<ctype.h>`, with the added bonus that there is no overload conflict if you include `<locale>`.

Comment: The C++ Standard defers to the C Standard for these headers; it says, *In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF` . If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.*  That's because it can be implemented using the character as an index into an array - negative characters can then index out of bounds.  See [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](/a/21805970/4850040)

Comment: Ok, in your previous comment you mentioned conversion to unsigned (int), which would be the default. Though, if anything, just converting to `unsigned char` might be well-defined, but will give nonsensical results. If we're wrapping `::islower`, I'd rather execute it only for positive values, e.g. `[](char c){ return c < 0 ? c : islower(c); }`